# Selenium - How to set up env and browser variables and reference them testng.xml in GitLab

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, testing, gitlab, cicd

I have a selenium automated test suite that runs on the GitLab pipeline and my testng.xml file has a few parameters such as env and browser hardcoded. The `.yml` file looks like this test:

```
stage: test
script:
  - mvn test -DsuiteXmlFile=pom.xml
```

I can create new variables in GitLab but I don't know how to reference them in my `testng.xml` and `.yml`. Ideally, I want to have the ability to select which env and browser I want to run my test on from GitLab.

Thanks